# How to get missing as a mean of all missing vector in julia-0.7?

Tags: julia

I'm using julia-0.7. The following code

```
using Statistics
x=[missing, 0]
mean(skipmissing(x))
```

gives 0 where `missing` is the built-in missing value of julia-0.7. If I further try

```
x[2]=missing
mean(skipmissing(x))
```

I get error message. What is the best way to get `missing` instead of error in the second case?

I'm afraid of using `if`/`else` because this snippet is iterated many times in the program.

Comment: I have given an answer what I think is best for now, but in general it seems broken. I have opened an issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest code I could recommend is using `if/else`, but I guess you cannot avoid it:

```
sx = skipmissing(x)
iterate(sx) === nothing ? missing : mean(sx)
```

as `iterate` should be faster than e.g. `length`.

However, in general you point to a problem that has arisen to me also recently, as there is an inconsistency in design of `mean`, because if you `collect` the you get:

```
julia> mean(collect(skipmissing(x)))
NaN
```

in case you have presented (so not an error nor `missing`).